# Hair direction wrong after simple deform

Tags: particles

After I have applied a simple deform modifier, e.g. bend, the direction of hairs are wrong (not all along the face normals). In the illustration below I have created a cube, and subdivided it to allow it to bend (left). I then applied the simple deform modifier on a copy of it, applied it (collapse the modifier), and created a hair particle system (middle). You can see that the normals are way off, they point in a different angle than the normals of the faces. I then created a copy of it, created a cube, used the same particle system on the new cube, and removed it from the problem mesh. Then joined them together (3), this seems to repair it after the fact.

[image]

I already have a workaround, which is create another object, in my case a cube, add the particle system there, and then join it with the faulty object.

But what am I doing wrong to get this problem in the first place?

A link to the testcase can be found here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=91560319569059047793

I am using Blender version 2.76b.

Comment: Hi and welcome to BlenderSE. Your question is too vague to receive good answers. Please add some screenshots and also consider uploading your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Done! Planned to do so, but wanted the question out beforehand. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: I tried to follow the operations you describe, but without reproducing the problem. Can you upload your file as indicated by @metaphor_set ?

Comment: Done, [here you go](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=91560319569059047793).